# Webview avoid security alert from google play upon implementation of onReceivedSslError

Tags: android

I am getting security alert from google play saying:

> Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

If I remove onReceivedSslError (handler.proceed()), page won't open.
Is there anyway I can open page in webview and avoid security alert.

and my website to put in my app need http or https ? I'm using http://mywebsite...

Comment: Have you updated to the latest `targetPlatform` and/or `platformTools`?

Comment: I'm using the latest version

Answer (score 0):

If you use **onReceivedSslError** method, then please remove **onReceivedSslError** method and make new APK.

Comment: If I remove onReceivedSslError (handler.proceed()), page won't open. Is there anyway I can open page in webview and avoid security alert.

Answer (score 0):

Change onReceivedSslError() to:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView v, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setMessage("Problem with Security");
    builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Hope this will help you.